# Insert query works sometimes but sometimes it doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I wrote this php code to submit all the entries in the form into the database but I am getting a strange problem. The insert query works sometimes but other times doesn't and it shows 'Error querying database'. I have checked the id's of all the HTML fields a hundred times and they are absolutely fine. All the columns in the database are also fine. Please help me with this error.

```
<?php
require_once('connectvars.php');
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to the MySQL server.');
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['name']));
$fathername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fathername']));
$dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['dob']));
$year = $_POST['year'];
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['email']));
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['pass']));
$confirmpass = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['confirmpass']));
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['address']));
$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['mobile']));
$rollno = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rollno']));
$coordinator = $_POST['coordinator'];



if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $output_form = false;

    //To check if all the form entries have been filled or not
    if(!empty($name) && !empty($fathername) && !empty($dob) && !empty($email) && !empty($pass) && !empty($confirmpass) && !empty($address) && !empty($mobile) && !empty($rollno) ){

        //Code to validate the form entries
        $domain = preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._\-&!?=#]*@/', '', $email);

        //function to check if the domain name is valid and it exists in the Domain Name System(if the web server is on Windows )
        function win_checkdnsrr($domain, $recType='') {
            if(!empty($domain)) {
                if($recType == '') $recType="MX";   
                exec("nslookup -type=$recType $domain",$output);
                foreach($output as $line) {
                    if (preg_match("/^$domain/", $line)) return true;
                }
            }
        }

        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._\-&!?=#]*@/', $email) && win_checkdnsrr($domain) && preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $mobile) && preg_match('/(DTU\/)? ?\w{4}\/\w{2,3}\/\d{3,4}$/', $rollno) && preg_match('/^.{6,20}$/', $pass) && ($pass == $confirmpass)) {


            $query = "SELECT * FROM reg_table WHERE email = '$email'";

            $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {

                //The user is registering for the first time, so insert into database
                $query = "INSERT INTO reg_table(`name`, `fathername`, `dob`, `collegeyear`, `email`, `pass`, `address`, `mobile`, `rollno`, `coordinator`) VALUES ('$name','$fathername', '$dob', $year, '$email', SHA('$pass'), '$address', $mobile, '$rollno', '$coordinator')";

                $test = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);
                echo $test;

                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error querying database');


                mysqli_close($dbc);
                $output_form = false;

                echo '<p class="success">Data submitted</p>';
            }

            else {
                //A user with same email-id exists
                echo '<p class="error">A person with this email-id is already registered</p>';
                $output_form = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            //the data entered is invalid
            echo '<p class="error">Please enter valid data</p>';
            $output_form = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo '<p class="error">Please fill all the form fields</p>';
        $output_form = true;
    }
}
else {
    $output_form = true;
}

if($output_form) {
```

?>

Comment: your code is crying to be refactored.

Comment: Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

Comment: @hjpotter92 what's the benefit?

Comment: use die('Error querying database'.mysqli_error()); So that you'll also get Error reason, from which you can sort out...

Comment: You wouldn't need to call/use `mysqli_real_escape_string` at all.

Comment: @ArchitVerma Kindly share what was the error, so that other ppl can know..

Comment: @Prashanth There was nothing wrong with the code. In the database table the primary key id wasn't set to auto increment so the query was trying to insert the data at 0 for all the fields. Thus, the query wasnt working properly.

Comment: To say `There was nothing wrong with the code` is wrong - you have at least 2 SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code - $year and $coordinator. You should refactor your code to make it easier to read - doing this will make it easier to notice problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with mysql inserting *sometimes*.  No errors.

I was doing mass inserts doing a batch process having put a pause in it works.

```
usleep(250000); // take a 1/4 second break
```